# Reversing lines and words

Tags: python, file, reverse

Gotta write a program that receives a file path and a "task" as inputs, and does functions according to the input "task".
if the task input is "rev", the program needs to print the file content in reverse (both the lines and the words).

I tried:

```
def file_play():
    file_path = input("Please enter a file path: ")
    task = input("Please enter a task: ")
    my_file = open(file_path, "r")

    if task == "rev":
        for line in my_file:
            for word in line.split():
                print(word[::-1], end=" ")
    my_file.close()
```

The text in the file:

```
i believe i can fly i believe i can touch the sky
i think about it every night and day spread my wings and fly away
```

Current output:

```
i eveileb i nac ylf i eveileb i nac hcuot eht yks i kniht tuoba ti yreve thgin dna yad daerps ym sgniw dna ylf yawa
```

Required output:

```
yks eht hcuot nac i eveileb i ylf nac i eveileb i
yawa ylf dna sgniw ym daerps yad dna thgin yreve ti tuoba kniht i
```

Comment: Don't split. Just reverse the entire line (`print(line[::-1])`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are reversing each word. What you want is to reverse the line like this :

```
def file_play():
    file_path = input("Please enter a file path: ")
    task = input("Please enter a task: ")
    my_file = open(file_path, "r")

    if task == "rev":
        for line in my_file:
            print(line[::-1])
        my_file.close()
```

Comment: Got really confused cause when I tried to look it up, most of the "reversing line from files" questions actually reversed the order instead of the line, so I thought I had to reverse word instead, thank you very much!

Comment: Happy to help. If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 2):

You can just reverse the line:

```
task = ['i believe i can fly i believe i can touch the sky', 'i think about it every night and day spread my wings and fly away']

for line in task:
    print(line[::-1], end='\n')
```

**output**

```
yks eht hcuot nac i eveileb i ylf nac i eveileb i
yawa ylf dna sgniw ym daerps yad dna thgin yreve ti tuoba kniht i
```

Answer (score 0):

If it is a string, then first convert it to a list
`a = "Hack it"`
`a = list(a)`
`a.reverse()`
`b = ""`
`for i in range(len(a)):`
    `b += a[i]`
`print("Reversed string/list: " + b)`

Output:

```
Reversed string/list: ti kcaH
```

Really hope this helps!